# How can I override a method in a ConnectionAdapter class in Rails 3 for use in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

In order to override the table_exists? method in the Rails PostgreSQL adapter I have tried the following in an initializer file:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  def table_exists?(name)
    raise 'got here'
  end
end
```

This will raise the the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
```

I believe this would have worked in previous versions of rails and I even found a [small plugin that did something like this in Rails 2.3.6](http://github.com/azimux/ax_fix_long_psql_index_names/blob/master/init.rb).  Also I only encounter this error when I am trying to run a rake task like db:migrate and not when I start my application server.

Could someone show me the right way to do this and / or explain why PostgreSQLAdapter doesn't seem to be loaded when I am in an initializer file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success by moving this code into a Rails plugin.  It is a little bit more overhead, but it is working consistently when I run `rails s` and when I run `rake db:migrate`.

I just followed the [rails guide page on the topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) and ran

```
rails generate plugin rails_patches --with-generator
```

and moved my init.rb file into rails as recommended.

```
~vendor/
 `~plugins/
   `~rails_patches/
     |~lib/
     | `-rails_patches.rb
     |~rails/
     | `-init.rb
     |+test/
     |-install.rb
     |-MIT-LICENSE
     |-Rakefile
     |-README
     `-uninstall.rb
```

I put this code in init.rb:

```
require 'rails_patches'
```

I put this code in rails_patches.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  def table_exists?(name)
    raise 'got here'
  end
end
```

This now behaves as I expected.

Comment: Trying this solution, I get the same error: `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter (NameError)`. (using rails 3.1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of config/initializers, place that code in lib/ folder.

While this means that the active_record is loaded after the rails initializers, which is unusual. I ll update this with more detail, once I am done investigating the whole flow. If you want some more details about the rails 3 initialization process, check out this link:

http://ryanbigg.com/guides/initialization.html

Comment: When I put the above code in the lib folder it doesn't even seem to load even though I have config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) in my application file.  Perhaps I just need to understand how autoloading works in general.  Thanks for the link, I'm reading through that.